# update a table in designer view in sql server in the same way we do in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We can update a table in designer view in Pl/sql by using following query:

```
select * from table1 for update
```

and than by unlocking the designer view and do further changes.

Can we do the same in SQL Server? I tried to do the same in SQL Server than I got an error:

> FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR

Guys any ideas??

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "update" - do you mean manually change the data, or change the design of the table, or both?

Comment: Aaron, In pl/sql oracle we can edit rows of a table with a select * query that ends with "for update".Using "for update" we can update a particular row in a table.I was thinking there should be some way to do the same in sql server as well.

Comment: That construct is not valid in SQL Server's flavor (Transact-SQL). In most cases you would use a *standard* `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Management Studio, right-click the table name in Object Explorer, and choose "Edit Top 200 Rows". If this does not return the row(s) you want to edit, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and this will allow you to modify the query that populates the grid. In all honesty, you should be learning proper DML (update, insert, delete) syntax instead of treating your table like a spreadsheet.

You won't be able to change the schema from the same designer, though; for that you'll have to use right-click > Design. (And again, proper DDL is better than relying on bug-laden and feature-restricted visual designers.)

Comment: Thanks Aaron,I was beware with that thing of edit top 200 rows,but Ctrl + 3 has done the trick i was looking for.But still it wont works if we want to update a particular row in a table. I agree with your point to apply ddl against restricted visual designer.Thanks Again!